# PostgreSQL: Selecting a DateTime that matches a whole day

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'd like to select every record that has a DateTime that's tomorrow, regardless of time of day.

however, tomorrow only refers to start of day tomorrow (after midnight). It's a point in time that doesn't cover the whole day.

so I can do this in my query?

```
WHERE myTable.my_datetime >= 'tomorrow'
```

but what < value do I put in after that? there's no 'tomorrow.tomorrow' and 'tomorrow' + 1 doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a function called [`date_trunc()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) wich truncates a part of the timestamp. So you can do something like this:

```
WHERE date_trunc('day', NOW() + INTERVAL '1 day') = date_trunc('day', the_column)
```

Comment: This is correct but if you are dealing with huge data, you must avoid to do this. Look at duplicate reason question instread, above.

Answer (score 1):

You can use date_trunc this way to avoid calling `date_trunc` for every `myTable.my_datetime` value in table, so it will run faster:

```
WHERE myTable.my_datetime BETWEEN date_trunc('day', NOW()) AND date_trunc('day', NOW() + '1 day')
```